# Long-range observation in space

Tags: science-based, space-travel

Explorers are in a spacecraft located 9 AU from a planet. Is it possible to detect fairly small objects (i.e. space stations, artificial satellites, etc., both powered and unpowered) using some sort of high-tech sensors (by which I mean at most sensors like what we have now, but more advanced)? How would this be accomplished?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I apologize, but the only answer to your question is "yes."  That's probably not what you were looking for, but remember Clarke's Third Law: any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.  If you're asking how it's done, there's mass and energy detection, but we don't know how to do it today.  So, can you clarify your question (by editing your Q)?  Also, bear in mind that we focus on worldbuilding, not storybuilding.  I stongly recommend following Secesiptus' advice and read through our tour and help center.  Some questions are off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting on closing of this question as it is to narrow and show no research whatsoever.
Yes, the proof is up there. Distance of 9 AU is Saturn from Earth. Do we observe satellites on Saturn? Yes, the Inuit group. And while they are rather big (12km -40km) we discovered them in XXI century. But we discovered the biggest in 2000, and then Tarqeq in 2007. They are all what you would say "inactive". 
Do we had active satellites around Saturn? Yes, Cassini was active for 13 years orbiting Saturn and sending data.  1/2

Comment: 2/2So there is possibility right now to detect object in that distance (and even further as Voyager 1 have 141 AU). 
So the question could be modified "can we detect specific object in white noise and among space trash while their call number is send in opposite direction of observer"

Comment: Look up spectroscopes they allow you to see the material composition of an object from lightyears away...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Rayleigh criterion (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution), highest possible angular resolution for a telescope is $1.22\lambda/D$ where $D$ - is telescope diameter, $\lambda$ - wavelength you are observing.

Let's say, you want an image in visible light, with wavelength around 500 nm, and you want to have 10 meter resolution. Required angular resolution is about $6.7*10^{-12}$ rad. Then $D = 1.22*\frac{5*10^{-7}}{6.7*10^{-12}} = 91044$ meters. So, to observe stuff in visible light you will need telescope with 91-kilometer mirror.

It will be less if you shift to UV, and you do not actually need a single giant telescope, but instead you can use many small telescopes with such distance between them. Think of a swarm of very precisely oriented mirrors, spread on area of tens of kilometers across. This will be your way to observe things.

Comment: @augmentedvarangian Please wait 24h before accepting the answer, you may have better answer in the future

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *FiatLux*! Nice answer. The comment above is just a general guideline for the OP, nothing against your answer personally. Waiting 24 hours on a more creative site like WorldBuilding can potentially increase the amount of answers and discussions as there is often not "one correct and many wrong answers", but a lot of answers that may work to differing degrees. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Nitpick: The Rayleigh criterion applies to the separation power of a telescope, that it, its ability to distinguish two nearby point sources. Such a large aperture is not need if all that's required is to see that there is *something* out there.

Comment: _Spotting_ an object is not the same as _resolving_ it. We can have a 10m artificial satellite that can't be _resolved_, but its heat signature will be so different from the background that we can positively say that there is a satellite there.